# Finding selected item from enum binded wpf combobox

Tags: wpf, enums, combobox

This is my enum class

```
public enum testservice
{
      New,
      NBG
}
```

I have used below ref in the xaml

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:testService"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

and i set the itemsource of combobox as shown below

```
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}"
```

But I dont know how to set the selecteditem of the combo ?

Also once everything is set, how to retrieve the selected item back from the code. Suppose i chose "New" value from the combo and saved in the DB. Next time when i open the window, how do i display back the "New" in the combo  box ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the property `SelectedItem` of the ComboBox to get and set the required value ("New" as you mentioned in above description).